# Record store in MySQL database with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'm now working on a project and wants to save Dummies-Daten/Werte in simple database with Hibernate and then read again. So I have few experience with Hibernate.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance
Luky

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple tutorial.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/hibernate/182-hibernate-tutorial.html

If you want more specifics examples, give more details like the database you use ...

This tutorial is for MySQL database.